# Active Directory domain controllers changes

Tags: active-directory

I'm writing to ask for your opinion about this.

### SCENARIO

I have *domain.local* (forest and domain tree root) with these domain controllers:

**DC1** | **SO:** *Windows Server 2008 R2* | **Roles:** *Schema, DomainNaming, PDC, RID, Infrastructure, DNS Server*

- **IP1:** 172.16.1.10
- **IP2:** 172.16.1.11
- **IP3:** 172.16.1.12

**DC2** | **SO:** *Windows Server 2008 R2* | **Role:** *DNS Server*

- **IP1:** 172.16.1.20
- **IP2:** 172.16.1.21
- **IP3:** 172.16.1.22

**DC3** | **SO:** *Windows Server 2012 R2* | **Role:** *DNS Server, DHCP Failover Load Balance Mode*

- **IP:** 172.16.1.30

**DC4** | **SO:** *Windows Server 2012 R2* | **Role:** *DNS Server, DHCP Failover Load Balance Mode*

- **IP:** 172.16.1.40

**Notes:**

- They are all Global Catalog.
- DHCP is configured to assign DC1-IP1 and DC2-IP1 as primary and
  secondary DNS respectively to clients.
- DC1-IP1 and DC2-IP1 are used as primary and secondary DNS (static) on
  servers and related applications

### OBJECTIVES

1. Assign DC1-IP1 to DC3
2. Assign DC2-IP1 to DC4
3. DC3 and DC4 will have only one IP Address: 172.16.1.10 and
   172.16.1.20 respectively.
4. Dismiss DC1 and DC2

### TASKS

These are steps I intend to follow:

1. Move all roles from DC1 to DC3 and wait for AD replication
2. DC1 - Remove IP1
3. DC1 - Run *ipconfig /flushdns*, *ipconfig /registerdns* and *dcdiag /fix*
4. Wait for AD replication
5. DC3 - Add DC1-IP1 and remove its IP (172.16.1.30)
6. DC3 - Run *ipconfig /flushdns*, *ipconfig /registerdns* and *dcdiag /fix*
7. DC1 - Demote and remove

Then apply the steps above (from 2 to 7) for DC2 and DC4.

What is your opinion ? Do you suggest to switch between steps ? Or do I forgot something ?

Thank you a lot.

Regards,
Luca

Comment: I don't get why you're making it so complicated. Follow [Removing a Domain Controller from a Domain](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771844(v=ws.10).aspx) to remove any DC you want. Just deploy a server that has the right configuration and add it as a DC to the domain instead of juggling all that junk. Is there a specific reason that it's not an option?

Comment: "Removing DC" is listed in my steps but set as last operation. "Just deploy a server": I already have it; it is DC03. So I think my steps are simply 
**detailed** but what you propose is pretty the same I wrote (I think)

Comment: Not entirely. Instead of having an establish DC that you try to coax into taking the role of DC1, I'd opt to decommission DC1 and setup a new DC in it's place that has the correct configuration from the get go. [Change the static IP of a DC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794931(v=ws.10).aspx) would make your plan valid. Still I feel like it's a bit complicated, though you probably have your reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove DC1, DC2 and DC4.

- Move all AD Roles from DC1 to DC3.
- Change DHCP to give just DC3 as DNS (check time for DHCP to lease IPs) and wait that time, so all the clients' computer get the new DNS).
- Demote DC1, DC2 and DC4 (to check replication check, AD sites and services that should be all running ok. Since you will only have 1  DC in the domain.

**For best practices Microsoft recommends to use 2 domain controllers at least on the same site.**

**UPDATED**

- Move all AD Roles from DC1 to DC3.
- Change DHCP to give just DC3 as DNS (check time for DHCP to lease IPs) and wait that time, so all the clients' computer gets the new DNS).
- Demote DC1 and DC2
- Change IP from DC4 to the one that had DC2. (now you have DC4 with DC2 IP)
- Change DHCP to give just the IP of DC2 as DNS (wait the time)
- Change IP from DC3 to match old DC1 (now you have DC3 with DC1 IP)
- Add DHCP to give IPs from DC3 and DC4 as DNS

---

Comment: I don't want to remove DC3. To simplify: I need to have DC3 and DC4 with IP addresses of DC1 and DC2 respectively. And remove DC1 and DC2 from infrastructure. I know how to do this, I'd like to know better steps order.

Comment: I have updated the answer (I thought you wanted to have just DC3, (not DC4).